# MVC best practice for seperation of concerns

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, scaffolding

I am using MVC5 to make a website.

I am using scaffolding to generate my controllers from my model-class. Whenever it creates a scaffold of a controller, the db-connection and model-manipulation happens within the controller class (look below). By looking at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694078/in-a-mvc-application-should-the-controller-or-the-model-handle-data-access) I can tell that most people agree that this should instead be happening in the model class.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Username")] User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
  return View(user);
}
```

Instead of having a controller do this, should i instead have it look like this?:

**User-Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "Username")] User user)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        UserModel userModel = new userModel();
        userModel.editUser(user);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
  return View(user);
}
```

**User-Model**

```
public void editUser(User user){
    db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

To specifiy what "db" is, it would be a reference to my db context.

Comment: If anything, it should be `public static void Edit(User user)` or `public void Save(DatabaseContext db)`.

Comment: You found one post where some users have given their opinion, and I could find dozens more stating that would be a bad idea

Comment: @StephenMuecke Pretty much all people in the thread claims that it should be seperated. Could you give me an example why it would be a bad idea?

Comment: Too many people use MVC as the pattern for their whole application. I would argue that MVC is more of a subdivision of your Presentation (GUI) Layer. The Models in MVC are usually ViewModels.

Comment: You are asking for opinions which is off-topic on SO.

Comment: But your biggest anti pattern is of course the scaffolding. Acceptable for doing CRUD on some simple tables but not suitable for building the core parts of any application.

Comment: @bommelding it certainly seems to be the case with my application. But yes, my website is pretty small and doesnt contain much more than simple CRUD-operations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstood what is meant with "Model" in the answers you referenced ([In a MVC application, should the controller or the model handle data access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694078/in-a-mvc-application-should-the-controller-or-the-model-handle-data-access)).

The answer of tereško states:

> The business logic in MVC and MVC-inspired patterns has to be in the model layer. And yes, model is supposed to be a **layer**, not a class or object.

So **do not** put database access into your ViewModel. Instead, you want a service class in your business layer that does the DB access and maps the database entities to Data Transfer Objects or ViewModels. Note how I use Command and Query classes to decouple the access to the business layer from any frontend classes like ViewModels (use [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/) to translate between DTO <-> ViewModel <-> Command/Query).

```
public interface IUserService {

    public UserDto CreateUser(CreateUserCommand command);

    public UserDto EditUser(EditUserCommand command);

    public void DeleteUser(DeleteUserCommand command);

    public UserDto[] FindUsers(FindUsersQuery query);
}
```

Controller uses this Business Layer:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(UserViewModel postData) {
     if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
         return View("Edit", postData);
     }

     var command = Mapper.Map<EditUserCommand>(postData);
     var updatedUserDto = _userService.EditUser(command);

     var updatedUserViewModel = Mapper.Map<UserViewModel>(updatedUserDto);
     return View("Show", updatedUserViewModel);
}
```

Comment: "model is supposed to be a layer", yes, next to the Business Logic Layer (BLL) and the Data Access Layer (DAL) and a few others.

Comment: Ahh, so i should percieve the DbContext-class as a part of my model? :)

Comment: The DbContext is definitely part of the DAL. It almost is the DAL.

Comment: @bommelding, `DbContext` is implementation of Data Access Layer. Usually Business Layer define abstraction of data access layer(interfaces) and Data Access Layer will implement them, where DbContext will be implementation details.

Comment: A DbCOntext does persistence, not business logic.