# Spring MVC write unit test for service layer which returns a view

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have to unit test my service layer but I don't know how to do it as I am new to SpringMvc.

Here is the method I want to test:

```
@Override
public String update(String username, User newUserData, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        updateModelData(model, "", result.getAllErrors());
        return HOME_VIEW_NAME;
    }

    User foundUser = this.userRepository.findByUsername(username);
    if (foundUser == null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException(username);
    }

    String queryResult = String.format("UPDATED SUCCESSFULLY: \n Old User: %s", foundUser);
    foundUser.setPassword(encryptPassword(newUserData.getPassword()));
    foundUser.setStatus(newUserData.getStatus());
    queryResult += String.format("New User: %s", foundUser);

    this.userRepository.save(foundUser);

    updateModelData(model, queryResult, new ArrayList<>());
    return HOME_VIEW_NAME;
}
```

**First** - I would like to know if it is a good idea to keep the `Model`, `BindingResult` and return a page in the Service layer? If no, why not?

**Second** - How should I test this method correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: First no because these should stay in your controller and your service should contain only the code to update/save your user. Second in unit test with mock.

Comment: Thank you! I will refactor this code to decouple logic from UI processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it's best to return *pages* in the **controller**. I believe the Spring developers created such annotations `@Component`, `@Repository`, `@Service`, `@Controller` is to also provide context for whichever layer that specific component belongs to. You can check [this discussion on SO regarding that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12694078/in-a-mvc-application-should-the-controller-or-the-model-handle-data-access).

On your second question, you may want to check out the [Spring MVC test framework](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework). You may want to check out `MockMvc`, there are tons of references in the documentation as well as on the [Spring projects repository](https://github.com/spring-projects).

I think you'd need something like the snippet below if you'd like to test your scenario where it went to the correct *view* after updating:

```java
MockMvc mockMvc;

mockMvc.perform(get("/path/to/update/resource"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(modelAndView().getViewName().isEqualTo("your_view_name"));
```